# Invoking a function in a closure

Tags: javascript

I am trying to creae a simpe page closure like this:

```
page = function () {    

    // define functions

    function clickAdd() {
        //..
        return "55"
    };

    var that = {};

    // object to return
    that.clickAdd = clickAdd;

    return that;
}
```

Idea is, I should be able to invoke clickAdd as then ...

```
page.clickAdd();
```

but, I get `page.clickAdd is not a function.`

What are my doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `page` is function, which *returns* an object that has a `clickAdd` property.  You'd have to *call* that function first:

```
page() // Call page ...
  .clickAdd(); // which returns an object with a clickAdd() function
```

If you didn't need to keep the `page` function around anymore, you could also just *call* the anonymous function and set the return value to `page`:

```
page = (function () {    
    return {
       clickAdd: function ()
       {
          return "55";
       }
    };
})();
```

Now, our anonymous function is called (note the `()` at the end), which returns an object with a `clickAdd` function, which is set to the variable `page`.  We can now call:

```
page.clickAdd();
```

In essence, `page` now acts like a static class.

You could also consider making the function a property of an object literal:

```
var page = {
   clickAdd: function ()
   {
      return "55";
   }
};

page.clickAdd();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to execute the outer function to get its return value stored in `page`.

```
page = function () {    

    // define functions

    function clickAdd() {
        //..
        return "55"
    };

    var that = {};

    // object to return
    that.clickAdd = clickAdd;

    return that;
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

page is a function in your case, so you will have to call it first:

```
page().clickAdd();
```